# CSS Flexbox help, getting items to align in a grid (image, title, text)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working to build the following layout as seen in the image below... The goal is the image is on the left with a fixed width. The text on the right of the image is aligned accordingly and takes up the available width.

Lastly, the goal is that these items stack in a grid.

[image]

I'm having problems getting the items to align properly, here's what I have:

```css
.feature-items {
  background: #CCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.feature-item--wrapper {
  background: #efefef;
  display: inline-block; 
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 336px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 88px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.img-wrapper,
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-items">
  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciate as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using, or wanting to use, flexbox, rather than CSS Grid layout, to align items into a grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to `.feature-items` and `.feature-item--wrapper` add display flex

```css
.feature-items {
  background: #CCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.feature-item--wrapper {
  background: #efefef;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 88px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.img-wrapper,
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-items">
  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature-item--wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://clipground.com/images/minecraft-server-clipart-64x64-9.png" width="64">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <strong class="feature-title">Title</strong>
      <p class="feature-description">This is a sentence description, hello world.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

These styles worked for me (with slight modifications).
And In HTML part check with the closing 'p' tag it is not closed properly

```
.feature-items {
  background: #CCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.feature-item--wrapper {
  background: #efefef;
  display: inline-block; 
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;/* changed */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 88px;
  padding-right: 24px;
    display: inline-block;/* added*/
}

.img-wrapper,img {width: 64px;height: 64px;}

.text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: inline-block;/* added*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. You have to set flex to the main container, not just for the childrens

```
.feature-items {
  background: #CCC;
  display: flex; /* changed */
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.feature-item--wrapper {
  background: #efefef;
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 336px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.img-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 88px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.img-wrapper,
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO Flexbox isn't really the best tool for something like this as it was originally designed for aligning items in one direction, horizontal or vertical. It makes much more sense to build a 4 x 4 grid using CSS Grid then use Flexbox to position the items horizontally inside your "feature-item-wrapper" div. See below:

```
    body {

    width: 50%;          /*   reduces available width so that */
    margin: 0 auto;      /*   items take up two rows. margin centers everthing */
    }

    .feature-items {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px, 1fr)); /* minimum and max column width */
      grid-gap: 20px; /* seperates each grid item */
    }

    .feature-item--wrapper {
      background: #efefef;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .img-wrapper img {
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
    }

    .text {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

The top answer given, which you seem to have marked as correct, doesn't successfully stack the grid items on top of each other when on smaller devices. To make them stack I set a minimum width for the columns which forces the stack when the window reaches the set width. Also be mindful that CSS Grid isn't supported by legacy browsers.

Hope this helps :)